# Javascript/Html: Match two circles of same numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, canvas

I created a program that generates 4 balls on the screen with a number inside them.

When the user types in the values he wants to give to new circles to be generate and clicks the button, the new 4 circles with a number inside them get generated under the first 4 already generated balls.

However, what i want now is that if the ball numbers in the 2nd line match the ones in the first, then the ball should be displayed under that particular ball. But if the two ball numbers do not match then it doesn't matter.

Here is my code [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59p5k15q/). BTW JSFIDDLE isn't showing the result properly... It isn't showing any result on clicking the button but if u do it on your programming language. 
The button will actually generate the balls for you but if the ball numbers are same it will not place them in the 2nd line right under the ball of the 1st line containing that number.

```js
var arr = [];
var x = [];
var y;
      
for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
  arr[i] = 5 * (i+1);
}
      
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = 0;
var centerY = 90;
var radius = 70;
var temp;
var xar = [];

for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
  centerX = centerX + 100;
  
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();
  context.fillStyle="black";
  context.fillText(arr[i], centerX, centerY);
}

function go() {
  for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
    temp = parseInt(document.getElementById("one"+i).value);
    xar.push(temp);
  }
  
  console.log(xar);
      
  var xnext = 0;
  
  for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    xnext = xnext + 100;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(xnext, 190, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    context.stroke();
    context.fillStyle="black";
    context.fillText(xar[i], xnext, 190);
    
    if(xar[i]==arr[i])
      context.arc(xnext, 190, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="one0" type="text" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
<input id="one1" type="text" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
<input id="one2" type="text" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
<input id="one3" type="text" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
<input id="result" value="click here" type="button" style="width:70px;" onclick="go()">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please make a "**break**" from time to time :) It's pretty hard to read questions written like this.

Comment: sorry i dont know how to do that :/ i hope u can still understand it.. Really need help

Comment: @Mihailo ^^^^^^

Comment: By "break" `(<br> || \r\n )` I meant new line. Help is on it's way.

Comment: @Mihailo Oh yea lol sorry new to Javascript so dont really know much. Thanks for working on helping me with this program :) will be waiting for ur response

Comment: Is this what you had in mind [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/tametuv/edit?js,output)? If so i will post a detailed explanation as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to calculate whether or not the values are the same, if they are you need to set the Y to one value, else set it to another. Then you can use this Y value to set not only the arc, but the text as well

```
var calcY = 0;
if( xar[i] === arr[i] )
{
   calcY = centerY;
}
else
{
   calcY = centerY + 100;
}
```

Sample Output - http://jsbin.com/hazozafuha

Comment: hey, i tried something like what u suggested but it isn't working :/ is it working for u? If so, can u plz share ur codes with me so i can check where i went wrong plz :/

Comment: heres another hint `context.arc(xnext, calcY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);`

Answer (score 0):

## [JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/tametuv/edit?js,output)

#### Logic explained:

1. Take the numbers from the input;
2. Find the the numbers that are the same as the old ones;
3. Construct a "**skeleton**"(`constructed`) combining the old array(`arr`) and the new one(`filtered`), leaving the keys where they don't match empty/undefined;
4. Now check the difference between **constructed**-skeleton and **xar**-new;
5. Merge them together so the **empty** keys in **constructed** get the values from the **dif** array;
6. Pass the fully **constructed** array to you part of the code for making circles, and viola you've got 'em sorted out.

#### JS Code snippet:

```
var filtered = xar.filter(function(number){
    return contains(arr, number);
  });

  arr.forEach(function(el, key) {
    filtered.forEach(function(cel,ckey){
      if (el === cel){
        constructed[key] = el;
      }
    })
  });
  
  var dif = difference(xar, constructed);
    
  for(var k=0; k<4; k++){
    var cval = constructed[k];
    if (cval === undefined){
      constructed[k] = dif[0];
      dif.shift();
    }
  }
```

> *I might have overcomplicated some parts but it certainly works. If anybody has some suggestions on how to improve this, I would love to check it out.*